# How to get IFRAME to snap to browser window height, minus constant offsets on top and bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page that consists of an IFRAME flanked on the top and bottom by status bars, each 40px tall. I'm using Twitter bootstrap's navbar class to provide these status bars.

The problem is I'd like the IFRAME to auto-size it's height to take up the entire browser window, minus 40px on the top and 40px on the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Create empty divs on the top and bottom that are 40px tall, with `position:absolute` `top:0;` and `bottom:0` respectively, and then make a div that strestches the mid section.

You will probably need to use the jquery `$(window).height(); to get the height of the browser window.

Hope your not opposed to a little JS

Answer (score 4):

Thanks. That worked. I did this:

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
   window.updateIframe = function() {
     var h = $(window).height();
     $("#iframe").height(h - 80);
   }
   window.updateIframe();
   window.resize(window.updateIframe);
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be:

```
window.resizeTo(window.updateIframe);
```